# Inserting comma delimited data into Cassandra

Tags: bash, sed, cassandra

I am tying to copy column data from a file to db column row by row.

myFile-

```
'LB333','HK8','2015-05-23 16:20:00+0000',''
```

so to perform insert operation i wrote following sed statement-

```
        sed "s/' *, *'/' '/g;s/\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)/INSERT INTO home.BOM_WHERE (prod_id, id, effective_date, revision ,type ) VALUES (\1,\2,\3, \4, 'COMPONENT');s/' '/','/g" myFile
```

The following value should add at these places-

```
    \1 - 'LB333' - against column prod_id
    \2- 'HK8' - against column id
    \3 -'2015-05-23 16:20:00+0000' - against column effective_date
    \4- '' - against column revision
    \5- 'COMPONENT'- hardcodded i am inserting- against column type
```

So for the first four value i wanted to copy from file for last column am passing harcodded value as per my requirement.

the above sed statement didnt work. Kindly suggest

Comment: This a perfect case for using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). Don't involve `sed`, please.

Comment: @John1024 Sir i updated my post

Comment: @tadman Sorry sir, by mistak i have tagged asa mysql. This column data am inserting in cassandra table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a simple `read` :

```
while IFS=',' read a b c d; do
echo "INSERT INTO home.BOM_WHERE (prod_id, id, effective_date, revision ,type ) VALUES ($a,$b,$c,$d,'COMPONENT')"
done < file
```

Output :

```
INSERT INTO home.BOM_WHERE (prod_id, id, effective_date, revision ,type ) VALUES ('LB333','HK8','2015-05-23 16:20:00+0000', '', 'COMPONENT')
```

Comment: @okla I've removed the `sed` part of my answer. See @Jonathan Leffler's answer for better comments on your sed command.

Answer (score 2):

In your existing `sed`, you have (in effect):

```
sed -e "s/' *, *'/' '/g" \
    -e "s/\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)/INSERT INTO home.BOM_WHERE (prod_id, id, effective_date, revision ,type ) VALUES (\1,\2,\3, \4, 'COMPONENT')" \
    -e "s/' '/','/g"
```

The first expression carefully removes the commas; the second expression tries to match on the commas that have been removed — and fails, oddly enough.

Apart from some tidying up, this code does the job, and is basically your middle `s///` operation without the two outer `s///` statements:

```
sed -e "s/^\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)$/INSERT INTO home.BOM_WHERE (prod_id, id, effective_date, revision, type) VALUES (\1, \2, \3, \4, 'COMPONENT')/" "$@"
```

That's a long line, but it works for me, producing:

```
INSERT INTO home.BOM_WHERE (prod_id, id, effective_date, revision, type) VALUES ('LB333', 'HK8', '2015-05-23 16:20:00+0000', '', 'COMPONENT')
```